# Write mongodb query using Count , DISTINCT & SUM for the following scenario

Tags: mysql, mongodb, aggregation-framework

mysql :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col1, col2) AS 'aggCol1',
SUM(col3 = "2016-03-04 00:00:00" AND col5 = 29) AS 'aggCol2' 
FROM table1 
WHERE col4 = 50;
```

I want to write the query on MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Aggregation Framework:

To filter by `col4` you should use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html)

To transform your collection into single result you need [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/group/index.html) with `_id` set to `null`

To get distinct values for `col1` and `col2` you can use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/index.html)

To use nested filtering for `col3` and `col5` you need [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html)

To get array length you can use [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html)

So entire aggregation should look like this:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { col4: 50 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            c12: { $addToSet: { col1: "$col1", col2: "$col2" } },
            c3: { $push: { col3: "$col3", col5: "$col5" } }
        }
    },
    {
       $project: {
            c12: 1,
            c3: {
               $filter: {
                  input: "$c3",
                  as: "item",
                  cond: { $and: [
                    { $eq: [ "$$item.col3", ISODate("2016-03-04") ] },
                    { $eq: [ "$$item.col5", 29 ] }
                  ] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            aggCol1: { $size: "$c12" },
            aggCol2: { $size: "$c3" }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks mickl, but it shows error "$reduce found an unknown argument: as".
Also I updated my query as above.

Comment: @Prasanti updated my answer, there should be `initialvalue` in $reduce.  Regarding your question: what does it mean SUM(col3 > 30 AND col5 = 29) ? You want col3 + col5 but only on rows matching both conditions ?

Comment: Yes mickl, it should check the condition rows withcondition 'col3 = "2016-03-04 00:00:00" AND col5 = 29' and count the specific rows. 
Lets consider here col3 contains a date value .

Comment: So you need COUNT OR SUM ?

Comment: ya its equivalent to count in mySQL.
It means count the no. of rows which meet the condition 'col3 = "2016-03-04 00:00:00" AND col5 = 29'

Comment: @Prasanti, so you don't need $reduce, try my updated answer

Comment: sorry @mickl but I'm not getting the correct result for "aggCol2" :(

Comment: Is col3 of type string or Date ? or please paste one sample document from your collection

Comment: If i'm checking only for integer part [ col5 = 29], that also doesn't give correct output

Comment: Thanks a lot @mickl, It worked . Got the output as expected. The column value is of type string [ col5 = "29"]